# iPad <-> iPhone GameKit connection over bluetooth possible?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad, bluetooth, gamekit

Has anyone established GameKit connectivity between an iPhone app running on an iPad and an iPhone app running on an iPhone?  I tried the GKTank example and they won't connect.  The iPad throws a "Error: 30509 -- Bluetooth not available.." error when trying to connect.

Comment: So despite the console saying no BT - it was in fact a problem with my iPhone.  A hard reset of the phone solved the connectivity problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on Bluetooth on the iPad?  There's a switch in Settings, it's off by default.